# How can I use an ember-cli-addon without ember-cli?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

we are migrating an ember project from version 1.9.0 to the current version. We are not using ember-cli, and as the ember guys pointed out, it is not necessary. We used some plugins with version 1.9.0 that are not working in later versions anymore [like this stuff](http://addepar.github.io/ember-widgets/#/ember-widgets/overview)

So we want to replace this old plugins with stuff from [here (emberAddons.com)](http://www.emberaddons.com/?query=selectiz).

I have no Idea how to get just the css and js files I need to include into my project from these addons. I already have downloaded the the code from ember-cli-selectize and tried to build it with ember, but, as I always expect from "npm & node & only god knows what dependencies here are breaking", I only get errors:

```
d:\ember-cli-selectize-master>ember build
Arguments to path.join must be strings
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at Object.win32.join (path.js:233:13)
    at AddonDiscovery.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon-discovery.js:114:24)
    at Array.map (native)
    at AddonDiscovery.discoverFromDependencies (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon-discovery.js:104:68)
    at AddonDiscovery.discoverChildAddons (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon-discovery.js:71:31)
    at Class.Addon.discoverAddons (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon.js:217:40)
    at Class.Addon.initializeAddons (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon.js:230:8)
    at setupRegistryForEachAddon (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\ember-cli-preprocess-registry\preprocessors.js:18:10)
    at Object.module.exports.setupRegistry (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\ember-cli-preprocess-registry\preprocessors.js:46:3)
    at Class.Addon (C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon.js:105:5)
```

By the way, we are working with Visual Studio, WebApi and Ember.js.

Comment: The plugin you linked to no longer works because it uses views, it is unrelated to the ember-cli.

Comment: you mean the Addeppar ember widgets?

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/Addepar/ember-widgets/blob/21dec8379262a01550265e91b92e6aaae7d982d3/src/templates/select.hbs#L5)

Comment: did you read my post to the end?

Comment: My bad, missed the I want to replace part.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ember-giftwrap](https://github.com/ef4/ember-giftwrap). It is meant to take a number of Ember addons and package them into a standard JavaScript file that can be injected into any Ember application.